# How do I ensure my jruby command line options are used when running "rails", "rake", "rspec" etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, jrubyonrails

I currently run my Rails app using:

```
jruby --1.9 -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -S rails server
```

This is getting pretty old now. How can I set my Rails project up so that just running

```
rails server
```

has the same effect?

(Note: bash aliases and the like are not what I'm looking for here. I want to make the project work right, not fix my local settings)

Comment: Hmm, I've found PROJECT_JRUBY_OPTS in my .rvmrc which looks like it should solve this. However, it doesnt seem to work. Even more puzzlingly, setting JRUBY_OPTS via an export won't stick, which implies that RVM is doing something weird.

Comment: Asked about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283300/how-do-i-use-jruby-opts-with-rvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using RVM and a project .rvmrc, the canonical way is to set PROJECT_JRUBY_OPTS in the project .rvmrc. A bug prevented this from working for me, so use [rvm head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283300/how-do-i-use-jruby-opts-with-rvm).

If not using rvm then use JRUBY_OPTS, which is the built-in way of doing it that JRuby checks (in fact, the PROJECT_JRUBY_OPTS thing ends up being converted to JRUBY_OPTS by rvm).