# How do I use JRUBY_OPTS with RVM?

Tags: jruby, rvm, jrubyonrails

It seems that the idiomatic way to provide flags to JRuby in an RVM-based Rails project is to set the environmental variable JRUBY_OPTS or PROJECT_JRUBY_OPTS, the latter perhaps being done automatically, since I see I can uncomment this line from my project directory's `.rvmrc`:

```
PROJECT_JRUBY_OPTS=( --1.9 )
```

However, that line seems to do nothing, and if I set the environmental variables, RVM actually unsets them.

So, how am I supposed to do this?

(Note that I have this at the bottom of my .bashrc file, which is how I believe I'm supposed to use rvm:)

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

#### Example:

```
$ JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9 jruby -v
jruby 1.6.5 (ruby-1.9.2-p136) (2011-10-25 9dcd388) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_27) [darwin-x86_64-java]

$ export JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9
$ jruby -v
jruby 1.6.5 (ruby-1.8.7-p330) (2011-10-25 9dcd388) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_27) [darwin-x86_64-java]
$ env | grep JRUBY_OPTS
[empty result]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

this option was parsed with jruby nailgun hook only, i have added a new hook to parse only this options (no ng):

```
rvm get head
chmod +x ${rvm_path}/hooks/after_use_jruby_opts
```

and it should work upon entering directory with this option

Answer (score 13):

I put `export JRUBY_OPTS="..."` in my project's `.rvmrc`, at the bottom of the file. This works for me.

```
export JRUBY_OPTS="--1.9 -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -J-Xmx1024m"

$ jruby -v
jruby 1.6.5 (ruby-1.9.2-p136) (2011-10-25 9dcd388) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_29) [darwin-x86_64-java]
```

Answer (score 5):

@mpapis identified the problem and provided the fix.  Here's some additional background.  TL;DR: use `PROJECT_JRUBY_OPTS` and the jRuby hooks.

jRuby uses `JRUBY_OPTS` to configure jRuby's behavior.

RVM supports `PROJECT_JRUBY_OPTS` with two provided hook files (currently, `after_use_jruby` and `after_use_jruby_opts`).  If enabled by making them executable, the hooks use the script library functions `jruby_options_append` and `jruby_options_remove` to append/remove the options in `PROJECT_JRUBY_OPTS` to/from `JRUBY_OPTS`.

So, you have two options.

If you install the latest RVM, you can roll your own per-project .rvmrc, and you can set environment variables and run commands, as you would expect.  No additional steps are required.

```
$ cat >> ~/tmp/.rvmrc
export JRUBY_OPTS='--1.9'
^D
```

And then:

```
$ cd ~/tmp
$ env | grep OPTS
JRUBY_OPTS='--1.9'
```

Or you can enable the jruby hooks, generate an .rvmrc, and customize it:

```
$ chmod +x ${rvm_path}/hooks/after_use_jruby_opts # or after_use_jruby
```

Then:

```
$ cd ~/tmp
$ rvm --rvmrc --create jruby@projectxyz # edit the resulting .rvmrc, uncomment PROJECT_JRUBY_OPTS
```

And now:

```
$ cd ~/tmp
$ env | grep OPTS
JRUBY_OPTS='--1.9'
```

There are subtle differences to the two approaches.

With the first approach, the changes to `JRUBY_OPTS` persist even if you navigate back out of the  project directory.  With the second approach, the project-specific options are removed from the `JRUBY_OPTS` environment variable when you navigate out of the project directory.

Likewise, the first case overwrites `JRUBY_OPTS` with the value in .rvmrc, while the second case intelligently appends the project-specific information.

@paul-biggar, unfortunately I wasn't able to duplicate the problem where RVM unset `JRUBY_OPTS`.

Comment: The PROJECT_JRUBY_OPTS flag is part of rvm - we use a standard .rvmrc generated by rvm, and looking through the code for rvm, I see that it reads PROJECT_JRUBY_OPTS and assigns it to JRUBY_OPTS. However, I did try your suggestion, and it still didnt work. I think rvm is unsetting JRUBY_OPTS.

Answer (score 5):

Since your are using rvm just create a file .ruby-env in your directory folder.
Inside the file you can define your custom env.
Like:

```
JRUBY_OPTS=-Xcext.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your .bashrc file

```
export JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9
```

It's working fine for me